# ADFS Certificate based authentication

Tags: adfs, windows-server

While implementing ADFS Certificate based authentication. I am getting the following error.

Exception details:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenHandler.KerberosCertificateLogon(X509Certificate2 certificate)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.WindowsClaimsIdentity.CertificateLogon(X509Certificate2 x509Certificate)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.WindowsClaimsIdentity.CreateFromCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean useWindowsTokenService, String issuerName)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISX509SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.GetEffectivePrincipal(SecurityTokenElement securityTokenElement, SecurityTokenHandlerCollection securityTokenHandlerCollection)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken request, IList1& identityClaimSet)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(MSISRequestSecurityToken signInRequest, Uri& replyTo, IList1& identityClaimCollection)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestSingleSingOnToken(ProtocolContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.BuildSsoSecurityToken(WSFederationSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken, SecurityToken& ssoSecurityToken)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.ProcessSingleSignOn(ProtocolContext context)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolTlsClientListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolTlsClientListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Answer (score 0):

Does the user account that your process is running under have access to the private key in your certificate store? If not, via MMC->Certificates->all Tasks->Manage Private keys and make sure that the account (assuming it is not your account) is in that list.